# Joining task-parallel threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I know how to join a simple thread to make parent thread wait for them but I don't know how to do it for automatic threads implemented in System.Threading.Tasks namespace . Here's an example . I call two functions in my main function that I want to be executed respectively . Each function has an parallel.for inside it . Now how can I make the main thread wait for all threads of first function to get finished before calling second function ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     fill();
     // now main should wait for threads of fill function to finish
     filter();
}

void filter()
{
     parallel.for(some action);
}

void fill()
{
    parallel.for(some action);
}
```

Comment: `Parallel.For` blocks until all tasks have completed anyway...

Comment: Parallel.For is already joined theoritically. It will wait till all tasks finishes.

Comment: I'm not sure . because when I use it , I get conflicted result and when I use regular for , everything is OK !

Comment: If you will enable hyper-threading or unlock some cores, then you may put those some actions in same single parallel.for . Otherwise both cases would not change total time.

Comment: If your results are as expected with a synchronous `for...` loop, I'd say you have a shared resource being used in your parallel loops. That isn't a good idea.. because locking access to them will basically make it synchronous anyway. Ideally you would use `Parallel.For` for blocks of unrelated data.

Comment: What `conflicted results` are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

[Parallel.For Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) internally fork iteration among multiple threads, but then it blocks till they all finish. Therefore your code is a sequence code in point of view of the main function:

> we fork the processing of loop iterations, and we join such that the parallel loop invocation only
>   completes when all concurrent processing is done.

If you need some local state shared over the loop, use [Parallel.For Method (Int32, Int32, Func, Func, Action)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783299%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) version of the function:

```
public static ParallelLoopResult For<TLocal>(
    int fromInclusive,
    int toExclusive,
    Func<TLocal> localInit,
    Func<int, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal> body,
    Action<TLocal> localFinally
)
```

The below image depict how it works:

[image]

Here is a sample implementation of calculating parallel PI:

```
static double ParallelPi()
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    double step = 1.0 / (double)NUM_STEPS;
    object obj = new object();
    Parallel.For(0, NUM_STEPS,
    () => 0.0,
    (i, state, partial) =>
    {
        double x = (i + 0.5) * step;
        return partial + 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x);
    },
    partial => { lock (obj) sum += partial; });
    return step * sum;
}
```

For depth information about how Parallel class works along with examples, read [Patterns for Parallel Programming: Understanding and Applying Parallel Patterns with the .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222) (Blackquote, image and example are taken from there)

Comment: So why I get conflicted result ??

Comment: The problem may lay in the internal structure of loop body. Make sure you not relay on some share resources.